# Placing Google Custom Search Input Box Over An Image

Tags: html, css, search

Developing a wordpress blog. Wanting to install the GCS box over an image centered inside the page.

Example: Have an image 700px by 100px centered inside a page. I would like to add the custom search box over that image to create a "background" for the custom search box

Answer (score 0):

You could take the class/id of the search box and position it in the center of the surrounding div (image background) using position relative or absolute whichever works better.

If you need a code example just ask.